# Custom font not showing/extremely small?

Tags: java, swing, fonts

I am trying to use a font from Google Fonts. The `FontFormatException` is telling me there is a "Problem reading font data", and this seems to result in very very tiny text. There is thin black line on my empty frame, and I'm guessing that's my label. Not sure why I'm getting this exception. I tried a bunch of different fonts, all from Google Fonts, the issue is always the same.

```
public class View extends JFrame implements MouseListener {
    private JPanel content;
    private Font font;

    public View(){

        content = new JPanel();       
        content.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 500));

        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        add(content);
        pack();
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setVisible(true);

        try {
            InputStream file = Canvas.class.getResourceAsStream("RammettoOne-Regular.ttf");
            font = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, file);

            GraphicsEnvironment ge = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
            ge.registerFont(font);

            font.deriveFont(Font.PLAIN, 25);

        } catch (IOException | FontFormatException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        }

        addLabel();
        revalidate();
    }

    public void addLabel(){
        JLabel label = new JLabel("this is a test");
        label.setFont(font);
        label.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
        content.add(label);
    }
}
```

I tried making the font huge in `deriveFont`, but no changes. 
Any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
font.deriveFont(Font.PLAIN, 25);
```

Needs to be:

```
// assign the derived (resized) font to the local attribute reference! 
font = font.deriveFont(Font.PLAIN, 25);
```

### Result

[image]

### Code

Here is the MCVE that shows the above screen shot.

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import java.net.URL;
import java.io.*;

public class TestRammettoFont {

    private JComponent ui = null;
    String fontAddress = "jar:http://dl.1001fonts.com/rammetto-one.zip"
            + "!/RammettoOne-Regular.ttf";

    TestRammettoFont() {
        try {
            initUI();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public final void initUI() throws Exception {
        if (ui != null) {
            return;
        }

        ui = new JPanel(new BorderLayout(4, 4));
        ui.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(14, 14, 14, 14));

        URL url = new URL(fontAddress);
        InputStream is = url.openStream();
        Font font = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, is);

        font = font.deriveFont(Font.PLAIN, 25);
        JLabel l = new JLabel("The quick brown fox (etc.)");
        l.setFont(font);
        ui.add(l);
    }

    public JComponent getUI() {
        return ui;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runnable r = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (Exception useDefault) {
                }
                TestRammettoFont o = new TestRammettoFont();

                JFrame f = new JFrame(o.getClass().getSimpleName());
                f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
                f.setLocationByPlatform(true);

                f.setContentPane(o.getUI());
                f.pack();
                f.setMinimumSize(f.getSize());

                f.setVisible(true);
            }
        };
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(r);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you!! That was the problem. Although I'm still getting the "Problem reading font data". But it still seems to be working.

Comment: I forgot to mention. Change `System.out.println(ex.getMessage());` to `ex.printStackTrace();` - it's shorter to type yet more informative. If you cannot figure out and fix the problem from that info, I suggest you start a new question, include an MCVE ([mcve]) hot-linking to the font as I did above & include the stack trace exactly as it prints out.

Comment: Will do! Thanks again!